# Query to get details about issue causing objects while changing database collation

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, collation

I am trying to change the database collation using following query:

```
ALTER DATABASE TestDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE TestDB COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
ALTER DATABASE TestDB SET MULTI_USER
```

When I am executing this, I am getting following error messages:

```
Msg 5075, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
The object 'Test_func' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed 
if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then 
retry the operation.
```

Is it possible to identify those objects only which are causing these errors? 
I could not find any query to locate such objects.

Comment: Changing the database collation won't change the columns' collation. It won't affect index performance or suitability for example, sort order etc. Why do you want to change the collation anyway? You don't need that to store non-English text - use Unicode types instead. If you want specific columns to have a specific sort order you can change their collation directly

Comment: Many objects can depend on the database collation so you will need several queries (computed columns, check constraints, objects with schemabinding and probably more I'm missing). Take a while to read this post to learn the danger for this https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/06/11/changing-the-collation-of-the-instance-and-all-columns-across-all-user-databases-what-could-possibly-go-wrong/

Comment: We are trying to normalize the collation between multiple databases and want to use only one collation for all the databases. So that development could be easy.

Comment: Why? Why is development hard now? If you use the wrong text type, changing the collation won't fix the real problem. If you store dates as strings, changing the collation won't fix invalid dates.If you use string concatenation, *all* problems including SQL Injection issues will remain no matter what collation you use. If all objects in the same database have the same collation you won't have any issues to begin with, only if you try cross-database queries

Comment: Even if you do need to change collation, do it *properly*. Use SSDT to create a database project - something you should probably already be doing. You should have version control for the database objects already. Find out the objects that need changing in the database project and change them there. Perhaps the *easiest* solution would be to create a *new* database with the new collation and copy the data, performing any transforms necessary, especially if dates or numbers are stored as text.

Comment: Finally, collation affects the codepage of varchar columns. If you simply change from one collation to another you may end up with garbled text or even lose data. The server uses the *collation* to determine what codepage is used by the text. If you use the wrong one, some byte values will correspond to *different* characters, while some others may not correspond to anything in the new collation

Comment: Thank you for your guidance and support. But technically is it possible to query the details of such objects in SQL Server, which cause issues while trying to change Database Collation?